# Q Microsoft Graph API for Onedrive always return 504 since last month on attempth to geting delta for drive for some drives

Tags: rest, onedrive

Request:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!giKJs_WIQ0SYORd____t9JdMRg/items/root/delta?$select=id%2cname%2csize%2cfileSystemInfo%2ccreatedBy%2cdeleted%2cparentReference%2croot%2cfile%2cfolder%2ceTag%2cmicrosoft.graph.downloadUrl&$top=100&token=MzslMjM0Oy___M7JTIzOyUyMzA

Response:

504 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!giKJs_WIQ0SYORd____t9JdMRg/items/root/delta?$select=id%2cname%2csize%2cfileSystemInfo%2ccreatedBy%2cdeleted%2cparentReference%2croot%2cfile%2cfolder%2ceTag%2cmicrosoft.graph.downloadUrl&$top=100&token=MzslMjM0Oy___M7JTIzOyUyMzA { "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "", "innerError": { "date": "2020-10-19T01:48:12", "request-id": "da95b695-56c9-4ac2-a102-8b0046d2aaee", "client-request-id": "023d3d5b-dbfa-4de1-a2b8-ec4847eb8752" } } }